# What does plus before key object mean?

Tags: typescript

Plus before key in object in typescript:

```
export type Action = {
  +type: string
};
```

Comment: Where have you seen it? It doesn't seem to compile on TS Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20type%20Action%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%2Btype%3A%20string%0A%7D%3B

Comment: there https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/reducers/types.js

Comment: I believe that's Flow, and it defines a read-only property. Check out https://flow.org/en/docs/types/interfaces/#toc-interface-property-variance-read-only-and-write-only

Comment: thank you! I will check

Comment: @FrankModica has what you're looking for but there is a `+` mapped-type modifyier operator in 2.8 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/03/27/announcing-typescript-2-8/

Comment: @JasonKleban Good to know, thank you!

Comment: The question has actually nothing to do with typescript. The file OP linked is a `.js` file.

Comment: @naeramarth7 agreed. It was retagged early on from typescript to javascript, and then I suggested an edit to change the post paragraph text from "typescript" to "javascript" to match, but this edit was rejected, and the typescript tag was put back in. It all feels a bit confused.